# LINQ filtering on a Dictionary<string, IList<string>>

Tags: linq

I have code similar to this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
dict.Add("A", new List<string>{"1","2","3"});
dict.Add("B", new List<string>{"2","4"});
dict.Add("C", new List<string>{"3","5","7"});
dict.Add("D", new List<string>{"8","5","7", "2"});

var categories = new List<string>{"A", "B"};

//This gives me categories and their items matching the category list
var result = dict.Where(x => categories.Contains(x.Key));
```

Key Value
A   1, 2, 3
B   2, 4

What I would like to get is this:
A   2
B   2

So the keys and just the values that are in both lists. Is there a way to do this in LINQ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Easy peasy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47644/what-does-easy-peasy-japanesey-mean):

```
string key1 = "A";
string key2 = "B";
var intersection = dict[key1].Intersect(dict[key2]);
```

In general:

```
var intersection = 
    categories.Select(c => dict[c])
              .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1.Intersect(s2));
```

Here, I'm utilizing [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but this gives me "2" as the result, but is it possible to retain the keys as well as mentioned in my question? I need the keys for further processing as well as the intersected results.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat dirty way of doing it...

```
var results = from c in categories
join d in dict on c equals d.Key
select d.Value;

//Get the limited intersections
IEnumerable<string> intersections = results.First();
foreach(var valueSet in results)
{
    intersections = intersections.Intersect(valueSet);
}

var final = from c in categories
join i in intersections on 1 equals 1
select new {Category = c, Intersections = i};
```

Assuming we have 2 and 3 common to both lists, this will do the following:

```
A   2
A   3
B   2
B   3
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be this complicated. :-(

Comment: Nope, it doesnt. I like your way of getting the intersections, but i didn't want to copy it. Feel free to add the dirty outer join to the end of your answer to "comply" with the requirements of the question, however, its better to use LINQ to get the categories instead of hard coding them.